# Iframe not passing url parameters

Tags: html, variables, url, iframe, parameters

I am loading a web page inside an iframe. If I load the page without the iframe I using the same url it works as expected. However if the iframe loads the url it doesn't work. I have tried googling it and all I can seem to find is how to pass variables in to an iframe.

the url is

http://www.angry-android.com/chartTest.html?start=2014-05-01&end=2014-06-01

and the iframe code I am using is

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.angry-android.com/chartTest.html?start=2014-05-01&end=2014-06-01" frameBorder="0" width=315 height=200 ></iframe>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLVED**

Turns out it is a firefox bug. The code worked as expected in other browsers.
My apologies should have checked that before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working for me:

```html
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.angry-android.com/chartTest.html?start=2014-05-01&end=2014-06-01" frameBorder="0" width=315 height=200></iframe>
```

Comment: are you getting dates? or does it say undefined?

Comment: I am indeed getting dates.

Comment: Looks as if it could be a firefox thing. Working in chrome and IE. Should have checked that first my apologies

Comment: @AntonyWalters, is there anything else? Did I help you at all?

Comment: indeed you did. not sure what was happening?? works fine  now though.